# Angular.js(UIBootstarp) Timepicker is showing ng-invalid class for input type="number"

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am implementing timepicker(UIBootstrap + angular.js).
ByDefault it uses the {{input type="text"}} for hours and minutes. 
it works fine but i m using this in mobile so i want to open the number keypad so i am using 
{{input type="number"}}.
So while using {{input type="number"}}, it is displaying the input type as "ng-invalid".

Comment: Thanks for your reply as i got the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error why it was as i am trying to display an integer `0 to 9` as `01 to 09` that will be as string so input type number would give error to display a string in `input type number.`